# why is my python format printing out the same variable instead of both variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

so I have a list that holds a tuple

```py
stat_list = [('name', 11212)]
print('{0:>16}   {0:17}'.format(stat_list[0][0], stat_list[0][1]))
```

My issue is that it's printing only "name" for both formats instead of "name" and "11212"

Why? and how could I make it print both? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number in the bracket group indicates which index in the format parameters to reference. Either remove the numbers or change them to point at the correct parameter. Example below, with alternatives.

```py
# Reference numbers before colon
print("{0:>16}   {1:17}".format(stat_list[0][0], stat_list[0][1]))
```

```py
# No reference goes in order of entry
print("{:>16}   {:17}".format(stat_list[0][0], stat_list[0][1]))
```

```py
# Unpack the tuple instead
print("{:>16}   {:17}".format(*stat_list[0]))
```

```py
# f-strings are a bit more clear (Python 3.6+)
print(f"{stat_list[0][0]:>16}   {stat_list[0][1]:17}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your updated code. It will work perfectly.

```
stat_list = [('name', 11212)]
print('{0:>16} {1:17}'.format(stat_list[0][0], stat_list[0][1]))
```

Please go through https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/